# Error in PXSelect for Acumatica 2022 R2 but not 2021 R2 on Custom Table

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have an SQL database shown here:

```
SELECT [CompanyID]
      ,[ScreenID]
      ,[BaseUrl]
      ,[UrlNumber]
      ,[DACNameList]
      ,[ParamList]
      ,[UrlVariableList]
      ,[Status]
      ,[NoteID]
      ,[PKID]
  FROM [DoorForms]
```

I used the ERP to generate a DAC from it like this:

```
using System;
using PX.Data;

namespace DoorForms
{
  [Serializable]
  [PXCacheName("DoorForms")]
  public class DoorForms : IBqlTable
  {
    #region ScreenID
    [PXDBString(40, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Screen ID")]
    public virtual string ScreenID { get; set; }
    public abstract class screenID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<screenID> { }
    #endregion

    #region BaseUrl
    [PXDBString(40, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Base Url")]
    public virtual string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public abstract class baseUrl : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<baseUrl> { }
    #endregion

    #region UrlNumber
    [PXDBString(40, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Url Number")]
    public virtual string UrlNumber { get; set; }
    public abstract class urlNumber : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<urlNumber> { }
    #endregion

    #region DACNameList
    [PXDBString(120, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "DACName List")]
    public virtual string DACNameList { get; set; }
    public abstract class dACNameList : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<dACNameList> { }
    #endregion

    #region ParamList
    [PXDBString(120, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Param List")]
    public virtual string ParamList { get; set; }
    public abstract class paramList : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<paramList> { }
    #endregion

    #region UrlVariableList
    [PXDBString(120, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Url Variable List")]
    public virtual string UrlVariableList { get; set; }
    public abstract class urlVariableList : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<urlVariableList> { }
    #endregion

    #region Status
    [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Status")]
    public virtual string Status { get; set; }
    public abstract class status : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<status> { }
    #endregion

    #region Noteid
    [PXNote()]
    public virtual Guid? Noteid { get; set; }
    public abstract class noteid : PX.Data.BQL.BqlGuid.Field<noteid> { }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

And I have code that works in 2021 R2 to select it:

```
internal bool CheckForDoorFormsOnScreen()
{
    var ApptFormInfo = SelectFrom<DoorForms>
        .Where<DoorForms.screenID.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>
        .View.Select(Base, AppointmentScreenID);

    if (ApptFormInfo == null)
        return false;
    try
    {
        DoorForms ApptFormSetup = ApptFormInfo.TopFirst;
...
```

Everything works fine in 2021 R2. But when I run the same code in 2022 R2, it gives me an error.

EDIT: I even have tried removing the WHERE clause like this:

```
        var ApptFormInfo = SelectFrom<DoorForms>               
            .View.Select(Base);
```

And still no rows are selected.

Stepping through the breakpoints, I see it runs the line of:

ApptFormInfo != null.

But there are no rows selected -- and there should be.

So, the line for:
DoorForms ApptFormSetup = ApptFormInfo.TopFirst;

sets the variable ApptFormSetup to null.

I copied the database file exactly. The code is the same. And it is workign in 2021 R2, but not 2022 R2.

Is this an anomaly in the upgrade?

Comment: Did you just copy the database or copied and upgraded it to 22R2?

Comment: I upgraded it. (It wouldn't have even allowed me to start 2022 R2 if the DB hadn't been upgraded. It checks it first thing...) I hand created the data in the new DB. (There were only 5 records) and exported them both out into Excel spreadsheets to verify they were the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is actually a simple answer, and I should have caught it sooner.

The company I work for ALWAYS sets the main company up in Tenant 2. EXCEPT, for whatever reason, whoever setup THIS one used Tenant 4. So, since all of my records have the CompanyID as 2, none of them were found.

It is worth noting (and remembering) that in PXSelect, you do not get to specify a CompanyID. It always uses current CompanyID as default. So, if there are multiple tenants your custom datafile needs to have the records replicated for each tenant.

But this is no bug. Acumatica was operating correctly. I made an assumption I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything works fine in 2021 R2. But when I run the same code in 2022 R2, it gives me an error.

If this answer doesn't get you to what you need, please post the error you are getting.

I'm going to overlook the fact that you appear to be selecting every record that has the ScreenID you stored in AppointmentScreenID, but it sure seems like you would want to narrow it down to a key field... which seems to be missing from your DAC. (IsKey = true on the field(s) that comprise uniqueness)

In your code:

```
var ApptFormInfo = SelectFrom<DoorForms>
    .Where<DoorForms.screenID.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>
    .View.Select(Base, AppointmentScreenID);
```

You are testing to see if ApptFormInfo is null. It shouldn't be null purely because "var" is translated into "PXResultset".  This means it may not have any records in it, but it will still be an empty list (not null).  You should test for (ApptFormInfo.Count == 0) instead.  If you just want to know if it found a record, that is enough... do your "I got one!" code in an *else*.

If you need to look at data, go ahead and enumerate your PXResultset more explicitly, at least until you get the result you want.  Then you can trim up the code again and test to see where you introduce the issue.

```
var ApptFormInfo = SelectFrom<DoorForms>
    .Where<DoorForms.screenID.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>
    .View.Select(Base, AppointmentScreenID);
    
if (ApptFormInfo.Count == 0)
    return false;

// Must have found at least 1 record, so either enumerate the list or do the "got one" code
foreach(PXResult<DoorForms> result in ApptFormInfo)
{
    DoorForms ApptFormSetup = result;
    ...
    break; // if you want to just do something with the first record
}
```

Comment: Brian, thx for the reply. You are right, if (ApptFormInfo == null) is not correct. (I had figured that out after I posted.) But at issue is that I get no records back. See the edit where I take the WHERE clause out. I am asking to select ALL records, and I still get nothing back, even tho there are records in the file. There isn't an error message. It's just PXSELECT selects nothing.

Comment: Still an open issue? Did you ever add IsKey = true on any of the fields in your DAC?  I had an issue last week where I did the same thing, and the request returned 15 rows from the database, but the screen displayed the first record 15 times.  Doesn't sound like the same thing, but set your IsKey on the key field(s) of your DAC and see if something changes.  Otherwise, use Request Profiler to capture the SQL statements and run a query of the SQL statement from request profiler on your Dev SQL server to see if you can fine tune it to get down to what will retrieve the records you need.

Comment: Actually, this is simpler than that... In my company we *ALWAYS* set the main company up in Tenant 2. EXCEPT, for whatever reason, whoever setup THIS one used Tenant 4. So, since all of my records have the CompanyID as 2, none of them were found. So... all on me. I should have checked that. Thanks for the replies, Brian!